# Adding options to NSPopUpButton in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

So when I add an NSPopUpButton in Xcode's Interface builder, it automatically has 3 options in the dropdown which can be worked with in the IB; however, I want to have 8 options in my popup. I know I can just add these in code, but it would be much more convenient if there was a way to add them right in the IB, without making the popup button a property. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just drag NSMenu items into the thing?  They're in the object library.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you expand the NSPopupButton, there is a "Popup Button Cell". Expand that and you will find a "Menu". You can drag new NSMenuItems to that menu in Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: One may also click on an existing Menu Item on the drop down and press ⌘D to duplicate it.